# Docker ENTRYPOINT execute only first command in init script

Tags: azure, docker, shell, dockerfile, azure-web-app-service

I'm working on a Dockerfile, everything work as expected but when i try to create container from created image, only first command in entry point script get executed and other commands are not being executed, i have several services in a container and I'm trying to deploy it on Azure App Service for Linux Container Based and i followed every step accordingly but my other services are not being started.

In Azure WebApps for Linux Container, Nginx should be listening on port 80/8080 and SSH on 2222, else it will automatically stop the container inside webapp, So all these commands should be executed and all service should be started automatically.

> **My Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
WORKDIR /home/medrx
#add jdk 8
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk && \
    apt-get install -y ant && \
    apt-get clean;
#fix key issues
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install ca-certificates-java && \
    apt-get clean && \
    update-ca-certificates -f;
#set javahop
RUN export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java
RUN export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
#installing and setting up zookeeper
COPY zookeeper/ /opt/zookeeper
RUN true
#install vim
RUN apt install -y vim
#installing elastic search
RUN apt-get install apt-transport-https
RUN apt install -y wget
RUN apt install -y curl
RUN wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.13.4-amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i elasticsearch-7.13.4-amd64.deb
RUN update-rc.d elasticsearch defaults 95 10
# installing redis-server
RUN apt install -y  redis-server
#install nginx
RUN apt install -y nginx
COPY main.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
RUN true
RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
# installing tomcat
COPY tomcat/ /opt/tomcat
RUN true
COPY ROOT/ /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
RUN true
COPY service/ /opt/tomcat/webapps/service
RUN true
#copy front-end code
COPY html/ /var/www/html
RUN true
#install openssh server
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openssh-server
RUN echo "root:Docker!" | chpasswd
COPY sshd_config /etc/ssh/
RUN true
#copy init script
COPY init.sh /home/medrx
RUN chmod 755 /home/medrx/init.sh
#expose ssh n nginx ports
EXPOSE 2222 80
#run entry script
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/medrx/init.sh"]
```

> init.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

nginx
service ssh start
service redis-server start
service elasticsearch start
/opt/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start
/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
```

It's been secod day, i'm searching here and there but unfortunately no luck.
Any help/clue would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Standard practice would be to run Redis, ZooKeeper, Nginx, and your application in for separate containers, possibly using a tool like Docker Compose to launch them together.  Do not attempt to run an ssh daemon.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze Sir, These are requirements by the client and also docker-compose feature is still in preview on Azure. Do you have any idea why it's happening that way?

Comment: Did you try to change an order of your commands in init.sh?
Last should nginx -g 'daemon off;'

Comment: @AndriyBilous Yes, i did, but now the container exits automatically...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for helping, I'm posting an answer to my own question as i resolved it myself. The problem solved by executing the commands in parallel way and the i modified the `init.sh`  a bit like this and things started working.

```
#!/bin/bash
service ssh start &
service redis-server start &
service elasticsearch start &
/opt/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start &
/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh &
service nginx start
```